# Postgresql ORDER BY not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Let's try this simple example to represent the problem I'm facing.

Assume this table:

```
CREATE TABLE testing1
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    word text,
    CONSTRAINT testing1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and that data:

```
insert into testing1 (word) values ('Heliod, God');
insert into testing1 (word) values ('Heliod''s Inter');
insert into testing1 (word) values ('Heliod''s Pilg');
insert into testing1 (word) values ('Heliod, Sun');
```

Then I want to run this query to get the results ordered by the `word` column:

```
SELECT
    id, word
FROM testing1
WHERE UPPER(word::text) LIKE UPPER('heliod%') 
ORDER BY word asc;
```

But look at the output, it's not ordered. I would expect the rows to be in that order, using their ids: 2, 3, 1, 4 (or, if I use the word's values: `Heliod's Inter`, `Heliod's Pilg`, `Heliod, God`, `Heliod, Sun`). This is what I get:

[image: query 1]

I thought that maybe something could confuse postgresql because of the `WHERE` criteria I used, but the below happens if I just order by on the rows:

[image: query 2]

Am I missing something here? I couldn't find anything in the docs about ordering values that contain quotes (I suspect that the quotes cause that behaviour because of their special meaning in postgresql, but I may be wrong).

I am using `UTF-8` encoding for my database (not sure if it matters though) and this issue is happening on Postgresql version 12.7.

The output of
`show lc_ctype;`
is

> "en_GB.UTF-8"

and the output of
`show lc_collate;`
is

> "en_GB.UTF-8"

Comment: In `psql` do: `show lc_ctype; show lc_collate;` and add output to your question. Best guess it is the locale sorting rules at work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've updated the question to include that information. How could I see those sorting rules for that locale? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: That depends. The default Postgres locale collation depends on the OS collation provider, say glibc. You would need to find out your provider and then look up its rules. I have never done that so I'm not going to be of much help there. FYI, in Postgres 10+ there is the ability to use `ICU` library, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) 23.2.2. Managing Collations, provided the Postgres instance was built with `ICU` configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I've tried @jjanes's suggestion to use the `C` collation and the output is the one I would expect:

```
SELECT
    id, word
FROM testing1
ORDER BY word collate "C" ;
```

[image]

How weird, I have been using postgresql for some years now and I never noticed that behaviour.

Relevant section from the docs:

> 23.2.2.1. Standard Collations
>
> On all platforms, the collations named default, C, and POSIX are available. > Additional collations may be available depending on operating system
> support. The default collation selects the LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE values
> specified at database creation time. The C and POSIX collations both
> specify “traditional C” behavior, in which only the ASCII letters “A”
> through “Z” are treated as letters, and sorting is done strictly by
> character code byte values.

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct way to order the rows in en_US.UTF-8.  It does 'weird' (to someone used to ASCII) things with punctuation and whitespace, skipping on a first pass and considering it only for otherwise tied values.

If you don't want those rules, maybe use the C collation instead.